# Gradle 1.12 corrupts image files

Tags: gradle

My gradle version is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-04-29 09:24:31 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     a831fa866d46cbee94e61a09af15f9dd95987421

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.6.0_38-ea (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.13-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

The application folder path to images is:

```
myApp\web-app\src\main\webapp\images
```

By executing `gradle clean deploy` in the console, the following folder is exploded into my tomcat deploy folder, containing the image files:

```
\myApp\images
```

The deployed images have the same name and exactly the same size, as my project files.
The only problem is that images are corrupted and the image is distorted. Any ideas?

Update. The following code seems to be resonsible for file corruption:

```
    eachFile {
        it.filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                releaseVersion: project.version,
                releaseDate: buildDate
        ])
    }
```

I imagine that a possible fix would be to use another way to replace the tokens.

Update2.
The solution was, as some people mention it, to apply the ReplaceTokens filter only to some of the files, and to skip some file types. The following code works:

```
    filesNotMatching("**/*.png") {
        it.filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                releaseVersion: project.version,
                releaseDate: buildDate
        ])
    }
```

Comment: Do You have any SSCCE or source code somewhere on the web? Probably files are copied and processed (filtered) somehow during copying. Are You using filter?

Comment: I'm affraid that i dont have a source code that you can look at on the www. However, what filtering has to do with my problem? The application uses subprojects and a central build.gradle file. The only filtering that i see is something like :                    war {
            archiveName = rootProject.name + ".war"
            eachFile {
                it.filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                        releaseVersion: project.version,
                        releaseDate: buildDate
                ])
            }
        }

Comment: When files are copied into war file they may be filtered and binary content may be spoilt at that time.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Don't apply the filter on each file. Apply it only on files that should be filtered (and images are not part of them). See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filesMatching%28java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action%29 for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was:

```
    filesNotMatching("**/*.png") {
        it.filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                releaseVersion: project.version,
                releaseDate: buildDate
        ])
    }
```

Comment: You see, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: How would this change if you didn't want to parse PNG or ICO files? How would multiple patterns work here?

Comment: I guess that multiple filtering can be done with: filesNotMatching(['**/*.png', '**/*.ico', '**/*.jpg']).